# How to add existing taxonomy terms to node on saving

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I've a field organization_name which is term reference with unlimited values. Whenever somebody saves the node I want to attach a few more terms in this field.

I've tried doing using hook_presave and also using submit handler of Forms API.

But the problem is that they both expect the term to be filled with plenty other values as below. Where do I get those values? From taxonomy_term_load ?

This is the dsm out of the form_state array in the form submit handler.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using rules?

Answer (score 0):

The only place you need to add values in your `hook_form_alter()` is the `$form_state['values']` array. In there you should only see the `tid` value, not the whole term entity.

Alternatively, you can use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module

Comment: I did not ask this. I'm asking what values do I need to fill in tid array in form_state for example: tid, vid, name etc. Or can I simply attach the term object(converted to array) as is?

Comment: Is your `dpm()` in your question from `$form_state['values']`? What I'm saying in my answer is that you should not see all that stuff there, but only the `tid`.

Comment: No but I'm seeing all those stuff for all my term reference fields.

Comment: Again, the only place you need to add to in order to add field values is `$form_state['values']`. Since none of that other stuff appears in there, you don't need to worry about it. Simply add your `tid`s to the field's value array within `$form_state['values']`.